# System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection only partially implemented in Monotouch?

Tags: wcf, collections, mono, xamarin.ios, observablecollection

I'm consuming WCF services using the Silverlight 3 stubs and one parameter I need is a `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`. 
However the following code is throwing a `NotImplementedException`:

```
ItemType[] aItemTypes = ...;
ObservableCollection<ItemType> aTypes = null;
if(aItemTypes != null)
{
    aTypes = new ObservableCollection<ItemType> (aItemTypes);
}
```

If I use a foreach loop to add all entries manually instead of using the constructor that takes an enumerable, it works. Is there a reason why the constructor is missing or was it just forgotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a reason why the constructor is missing or was it just forgotten?

This sometimes occurs on Mono base class library source code when someone implement a type but does not need everything inside it. In such cases it's better to add *stubs* for the missing code since this:

- allow compilation of existing code;
- it avoid `MissingMethodException` at runtime, a `NotImplementedException` is easier to diagnose;
- allow Mono's tooling, e.g. **MoMA** and [Gendarme](https://github.com/spouliot/gendarme/wiki), to report the `NotImplementedException` on existing .NET code.

In this specific case I suspect that more tests were needed to see if the items being copied needed to trigger events (whgen adding them) or not.

The good news is that this method is implemented in Mono's GIT master. I'll look into backporting this into *mono-2-10* branch so MonoTouch will get it in future releases.

Comment: mono-2-10 was already updated (for Mono for Android, someone else must have it the same condition) so this method's *implementation* will be part of the next MonoTouch 5.1.x releases.